# Странное поведение в с++

Tags: c++, компиляция

Написал код, ошибок синтаксических нигде нет. Запускаю (использую Code::Blocks). Ввожу в консоль тестовый пример. И когда ввел первые два числа, то консоль начинает виснуть, как будто бы что=то считает, а потом даже если я пытаюсь дальше что-то ввести - выдает мне какое-то рандомное число!

Вот код задачи:

```
#include <iostream>

#define INFINITY 1000

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x, k;
    int m_min=0, m_max=0;
    cin >> x >> k;

 int *ind_arr = new int[x];
 int *num_arr = new int[k*3];

    for (int i = 0; i < k*3; ++k)
        num_arr[i] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
        ind_arr[i] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < k*3; ++k)
        cin >> num_arr[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < k*3; )
    {
        if (num_arr[i] == 0) {break;}       /*  if (num_arr[i] != 1 && num_arr[i] != 2) */
        else if (num_arr[i] == 2) {
            ind_arr[num_arr[i+1]] = 1;
            i += 2;
        }
        else if (num_arr[i] == 1) {
            ind_arr[num_arr[i+1]] = 1;
            ind_arr[num_arr[i+2]] = INFINITY;
            i += 3;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<x; )
    {
        if (ind_arr[i] == 0 && ind_arr[i+1] !=0){
            m_min += 1;
            m_max += 1;
            i += 1;
        }
        else if (ind_arr[i] == 0 && ind_arr[i+1] ==0) {
            m_min += 1;
            m_max += 2;
            i += 2;
        }
        else {++i;}
    }

cout << m_min << m_max << endl;
    delete [] num_arr;
    delete [] ind_arr;
}
```

А вот тестовый пример, который должен вводится:

```
3 2
2 1 
2 2
```

В выводе должно быть

```
  0 0
```

На мой взгляд сама суть задачи роли не играет, т.к. пробела тут не в верности алгоритма, а в том, что сам код вроде правильный, но при этом любой компилятор после ввода двух чисел тормозит, что-то считает и выводит это, хотя по коду видно, что дальше он должен требовать ввод данных!

Причем, когда запускаю код на ideone.com, то мне пишет в ответ

> Превышено ограничение на время

Comment: Я в с++ ни в зуб ногой, делаем ставки: этот цикл когда-нибудь закончится?

    for (int i = 0; i < k*3; ++k)
        num_arr[i] = 0;

Comment: Отлидчиком пользоваться пробовал? По всей видимости где-то происходит зацикливание.

Comment: Раскройте глаза -- в первом и третьем циклах опечатки. Дальше я не смотрел.

Comment: Подставьте вместо k*3 n, а где-нибудь перед первым использованием допишите n = k * 3 и будет вам счастье (наверное, алгоритм не изучал, сплю уже на ходу :))

Comment: `new int[x]();` даст вам сразу обнуленный массив. И никаких обнуляющих циклов писать не надо будет.

Answer (score 5):

В первом цикле увеличивается k, и конечно же условие i < k*3 будет верно до тех пор, пока не произойдёт переполнение значения k. На каждой итерации цикла будет обнуляться первый элемент массива. Что дальше — я тоже не смотрел.

Comment: Если компилятор придерживается strict overflow semantics, то он будет считать такой цикл бесконечным и имеет право генерировать код исходя из этого.